# Using WebBrowser control in an Azure webjob

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, azure-webjobs

Does anyone have any experience running a .NET console application which contains a WebBrowser control inside an Azure WebJob? Given that the WebBrowser control has a dependency on IE, I'm not sure whether the Azure WebJob runtime environment would support that dependency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will likely not work due to limitations in the sandbox that Web Apps run in. See [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) for details, in particular relating to GDI limitations.

Comment: Yes that was my thinking too. Thanks for the link.